# Moving or coping required data from one vector to another vector

Tags: c++

I have two vectors, A and B. A contains data in the form of row of a table based on some primary key, say row_id. Vector B also contain some data also in the form of row of a other table based on same key. Now my requirement is to pick only those data from vector A when row_id of both vectors A & B matches and proceed other functionality. How can this be achieved?

Comment: i suggest you try it yourself, or at least google (for real), and then come to us if you can show code that doesn't work and you don't know why

Comment: What does "when row_id of both vectors A & B matches" mean? Does it mean that vector B contains any element with the same row_id, or does it mean that for a particular index i, A[i] has the same row_id as B[i]? Or something else?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

If A & B data is like :

```
struct X{
int row_id;
int data;
}
```

Then you can probably use  [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) like following

Here C will be the vector having data from A & B where `row_id` matches

```
std::vector<X> A,B,C;
//Sort A,B based on row_id use std::sort with custom comparator

std::set_intersection (A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end()
                std::back_inserter(C), 
                []( const X& a, const X& b) { 
                return a.row_id < b.row_id 
                });
```

Comment: @POW That requires sorted vectors and you are missing B.end().

Comment: @POW Another thing: Use < to compare the id's (C++ uses less than for equivalence)

Comment: The answer is plain wrong, unless "a.row_id==b.row_id" becomes "a.row_id < b.row_id"

Comment: @DieterLücking fixed, anything else sir ?

Comment: Thanks POW & Dieter Lucking for your valuable suggestions I learned this new concept in C++. I implemented other logic to achieve this which don't require intersection. Once Bill Gates said give difficult task to any lazy person he/she will find easy way to complete the task, here same with me :)
Anyways thanks!!!